# Cannot subscribe to events from an ASP.NET Core 6.0 API NServiceBus endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, nservicebus

I want to make my API both publish events (outside any incoming message handlers, e.g. from an action method) and subscribe to events. Publishing events works. I used the older versions of `Program` and `Startup` to integrate using `GenericHost` and an `IMessageSession` is sucessfully injected into the constructor.

However, when the commented-out code is activated to make the API subscribe to and handle events, suddenly there is an exception about injecting `IMessageSession` being thrown when initializing the host and running the application.

**TestController.cs**

```
namespace TestContext
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase/*, IHandleMessages<ReceivedEvent>*/
    {
        private IMessageSession _session;

        public TestController(IMessageSession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }
        /*
        [NonAction]
        public Task Handle(ReceivedEvent message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }*/

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
        {
            await _session.Publish(new PublishedEvent());
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseNServiceBus(context =>
            {
                var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("Test");
                var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<LearningTransport>();
                
                return endpointConfiguration;
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

**Exception**

[image]

Why is the exception being thrown and how to make the API subscribe to and handle events?

**EDIT**

When handling the event from a separate service class, the exception is not thrown.

```
public class HandlerService : IHandleMessages<ReceivedEvent>
{
    public Task Handle(ReceivedEvent message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is actually pretty good here. Most of the NServiceBus exception messages are.

> Interfaces IMessageSession or IEndpointInstance should not be resolved from the container to enable sending or publishing messages from within sagas or message handlers. Instead, use the context parameter on the TestController.Handle method to send or publish messages.

So first, don't mix a handler in a controller. It needs to be a separate class.

Then, don't inject IMessageSession. That interface is explicitly for things like controller actions where you don't have an existing "a message is being handled right now" and you want to send a message.

Instead, if you want to send or publish within the handler, use the context:

#### Don't do this

```cs
public class MyHandler : IHandleMessages<ReceivedEvent>
{
    private IMessageSession session;

    public MyHandler(IMessageSession session)
    {
        // Won't work! Don't inject IMessageSession!
        this.session = session;
    }

    public async Task Handle(ReceivedEvent message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        // NOPE!
        session
    }
}
```

#### Do this instead

```cs
public class MyHandler : IHandleMessages<ReceivedEvent>
{
    public async Task Handle(ReceivedEvent message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        context.Send(new CommandToSend());
        context.Publish(new EventToPublish());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, separating the handler from the controller worked! Could you go a bit more into details - why can't handlers be controller methods? Does it have something to do with separate DI instances mentioned here: 
https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/web-application#dependency-injection-integration

Comment: I would turn this around on you and ask why you would _want_ a handler intermingled with a controller? A controller is a class instantiated by ASP.NET to serve a web request. An NServiceBus handler is a class instantiated by NServiceBus to process a message. Why mix them? Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle

Comment: I was creating a simple demo and put it there, no other reason. I don't actually want to have my controller and event handler intermingled as they serve vastly different purposes, but now that I learned it can't be done I wanted to know why.